# How to define a new command with counter

Tags: hyperlink

I am currently writing a report where I use hyperlink, as an example `\href{run:./Annex/MyTestResult.pdf}{Annex 4}.`
It works pretty fine.

However, I would like to add a counter for Annex numbering.
Is there a way to make this easier for example by using `\newcommand`? If so, how can I add a counter **and** use `\href` command?

Comment: `\newcounter{annexcntr}\newcommand{\annexref}[1]{\refstepcounter{annexcntr}\href{#1}{Annex~ \theannexctr}`, most likely? `\annexref{run:./Annex/MyTestResult.pdf}` should work then

Answer (score 3):

I'm no really sure what's the expected output. Following Christian Hupfer's lead, I reordered and cleaned up the code thus:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcounter{annexcntr}

\newcommand*{\annexref}[1]{%
    \stepcounter{annexcntr}%
    \href{#1}{Annex~\arabic{annexcntr}}%
    }

\begin{document}
    \annexref{run:./Annex/MyTestResult.pdf}
    \annexref{run:./Annex/MyTestResult.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Which renders as:

[image]

Comment: What does `clean up` and `reorder` mean in conjunction with my comment, apart from that it was a comment only, lacking display facilities and the fact that I've forgotten a closing `}` accidentally?

Comment: I took your comment and changed the `\theannexctr` to `\arabic{annexctr}`, and created a MWE. I also gave you credit for it. Feel free to post is as an answer, if you wish to.

Comment: `\theannexcntr` is the preferred way to display the counter value according to requested format. It falls back to `\arabic{annexctr}` if not specified otherwise... Taking comments of other users is not the way to start, actually.